# Get tax class ID by tax rate with REST API

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api, magento2.3

I'm trying to get a tax class ID with only the tax rate value, all with the API.
I found that I need a first request that returns me the tax rate ID :

```
/rest/all/V1/taxRates/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=rate&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=20
```

Then I want to request this API : `/rest/all/V1/taxRules/search` to get the tax class used by the tax rule (in my case we will only have one tax class, one tax rule for one tax rate so we know if a product has a defined tax class, which is its tax rate).

I search on the swagger and tried this :

```
/rest/all/V1/taxRules/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=tax_rate_ids&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=in
```

But I have this response : `Internal Error. Details are available in Magento log file. Report ID: webapi-5bf536f4a45a5`

I went to the logs and found this :

```
[2018-11-21 10:44:04] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5bf536f4a45a5; Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tax_calculation_rate_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tax_calculation_rule` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`tax_calculation_rate_id` IN('3'))) {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 42): Report ID: webapi-5bf536f4a45a5; Message: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tax_calculation_rate_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tax_calculation_rule` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`tax_calculation_rate_id` IN('3'))) at /var/www/html/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Webapi/ErrorProcessor.php:205, Zend_Db_Statement_Exception(code: 42): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tax_calculation_rate_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tax_calculation_rule` AS `main_table` WHERE ((`tax_calculation_rate_id` IN('3'))) at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:235, PDOException(code: 42S22): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'tax_calculation_rate_id' in 'where clause' at /var/www/html/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228)"} []
```

What did I do wrong ?

Thank you by advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please update your request like below.

```
rest/all/V1/taxRules/search?searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][field]=tax_calculation_rate_id&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][value]=3&searchCriteria[filterGroups][0][filters][0][conditionType]=in
```

It'll work for you. Let me know if any further help needed.

Comment: Please give an upvote if it was helpful :)